# switch statement with several values

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I am wondering if there is a way to evaluate several values in the switch expression. For example, I want to apply a case only if there is a match for X and Y. 
Here is my code:

```js
switch (x,y) {
  case x >= 0 && x < 150 && y == 150:
    topLeftRight();
  break;
  case x == 150 && y <= 150 && y > 0:
    topRightDown();
  break;
  case y === 0 && x > 0 && x <= 150:
    bottomRightLeft();
  break;
  case x === 0 && y <= 150 && y >= 0:
    bottomLeftUp();
  break;
}
```

Do you know if this is possible with switch? 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It is possible with switch as well

Comment: makes no sense to use a switch if it is not an exact match. use if/else if

Answer (score 2):

you need an if statement

```
if(x >= 0 && x < 150 && y == 150)
  topLeftRight();
else if(x == 150 && y <= 150 && y > 0)
  topRightDown();
else if(y === 0 && x > 0 && x <= 150)
  bottomRightLeft();
else if(x === 0 && y <= 150 && y >= 0)
  bottomLeftUp();
```

Case statements are good for checking if a single variable is equal to a list of multiple things. For example:

```
switch(vehicle.type){
  case Boat:
    print("This is a boat")
    break;
  case Car:
    print("This is a car")
    break;
  case default:
    print("This is not a boat or a car")
    break;
}
```

When evaluating conditionals, it is best to use an `if/else if/else` statement

Answer (score 2):

You could take `true` as expression to check against the cases. [`switch` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) uses strict comparison `===` of expression part and case parts.

```
switch (true) {
  case x >= 0 && x < 150 && y == 150:
    topLeftRight();
    break;
  case x == 150 && y <= 150 && y > 0:
    topRightDown();
    break;
  case y === 0 && x > 0 && x <= 150:
    bottomRightLeft();
    break;
  case x === 0 && y <= 150 && y >= 0:
    bottomLeftUp();
    break;
}
```